# When and which function is used for modifying file on sysfs of Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, sysfs

i'm analizing block layer's sysfs functions.

i added(attached) a file(diagram) which i made to explain function sequence flow of
/usr/src/linux-source-4.8.0/linux-source/4.8.0/block/blk-mq-sysfs.c.

I understanded these functions' relationship. but i couldn't find how kernel change values of attribute file. 
i heard that these files are created in the /sysfs/ hierarchy by calling sysfs_create_group() function.

When i do some I/O requests, system make some files like below.
(i use nvme ssd 750 series)

```
root@leedoosol:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1/mq/0/cpu0# ls
    completed   dispatched   merged   rq_list
```

kernel would have made these files to give us information about completed request numbers, dispatched number, merged number, pending request_list.

And kernel should have changed value of these file while dealing with I/O request. but i don't know when and how kernel change these value. 
i want to know when and how kernel change these values of attribute file because i have to find out what these values of attribute file means exactly.

here my environments.

1.) 2 socket per 10cores

2.) Kernel version : 4.8.17

3.) intel SSD 750 series
[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe I found answer. show store functions are called when i read my attribute file.
kernel don't fix their value of attribute file. kernel don't need to.

when i use 'cat' to the attribute file(in my example 'dispatched'), the file will be opened and then, several structs concerned with that file will be created in ram(of coures, in case of sysfs, backing store will not exist).

read() function will be called and then, show() function will called.